# merge Bootstrtap in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, css, bootstrap

I have a page made in bootstrap and i want to merge that page in visualforce.

Is it possible..Can someone please help me out here and let me know hou this can be done

Comment: It will be helpful if you can post the page here. You can always wrap you HTML page built in bootstrap with `<apex:page>` tag and set `standardstylesheet`attribute as `false`. You may have to remove doctype declaration and html tags and markup should be well formed

Comment: Have you tried ? Is there any reason why you'd think this is not possible ?

Comment: Thanks a lot..I was able to do it..Thanks a lot for the help everyone

Comment: @AnkitaSingh Consider either marking the correct answer or answering your own question. This might help someone with a similar question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty simple.

You can either upload Bootstrap as a static resource or, as I personally do, link to CDN. Bootstrap uses MaxCDN so alls you'd need to do is in your...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" />
```

... and your...

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

... is add the following as described in [Bootstraps site](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This will give you access to Bootstrap's classes. There are a couple of things to consider including, but not limited to:

- Including, at the very least the "apex:page" tags
- Ensure any unclosed tags are closed with a "/"
- Although not absolutely necessary, you might want to add "*standardStyleSheets="false"*" in the "*apex:page*" markup to remove any SFDC styling

You can then use any Visualforce markup and use any bootstrap classes by (normally) adding the "*styleClass=''*" parameter.

**Edit:** Also consider this comment from Eric:

> With the caveat that unless the Bootstrap is namespaced, it will
>   affect the Look and feel of the sidebar and header. If you are not
>   displaying those then you will not need to namespace bootstrap. There
>   are also instances, even with a NS bootstrap that salesforce CSS
>   throws a wrench into the mix and you have to do some manual
>   intervention

Comment: With the caveat that unless the Bootstrap is namespaced, it will affect the Look and feel of the sidebar and header. If you are not displaying those then you will not need to namespace bootstrap. There are also instances, even with a NS bootstrap that salesforce CSS throws a wrench into the mix and you have to do some manual intervention

Comment: Good point there. Typically I disable the sidebar and header when using this. The only affect bootstrap seems to have on the header when I still include that is a change of font and a bit bolder.