# How to apply bootstrap "alert class" to pageMessage?

Tags: apex, visualforce, bootstrap

How can I apply `bootstrap to pageMessages` component on vf page?

I am getting pageMessage in standard format but I want it to display it using `alert-success style class`. Can anyone help?

Comment: use bootstrap alert http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_alerts.asp and use `apex:massages` inside div  `<div class="alert alert-danger">
  <strong>Danger!</strong> <apex:messages />
</div>` ... try this may you want

Comment: Check the accepted answer here, there's some good advice. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/95605/merge-bootstrtap-in-visualforce

Comment: this might help you http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104000/error-message-in-visualforce-page/104001#104001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure (something I read on this forum, I just can't find the question!) you can't apply Bootstrap classes to `<apex:pageMessage>` directly or easilly, at least not in the same way you would using things like `styleClass`.

I suppose this is because Bootstrap's error messages contain a containing element with children, whereas Salesforce's `<apex:pageMessage>` renders any child elements at runtime.

Instead, you could use a boolean which, if set to true, will show a message.

In your class you'd want something like this:

```
public Boolean itFailed {
    get {
        if (itFailed == null)
            itFailed = false;
    }
}
```

Then whatever function you're using to call something like:

```
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Oops!' + e));
```

For the `Apex:PageMessage`, you would just set `itFailed` to true as an example.

To make sure this message only appears if it's set to true, you can use the `rendered=` parameter: `rendered="{!itFailed}"` in an `outputPanel` or something with your Bootstrap HTML and classes inside. In other words, that `outputPanel` will only display if the `itFailed` variable is set to true.

As a result, you can have completely customised error or success messages with complete control over what they look like. You'll just have to manage when they appear in the controller, controlling that Boolean and being sure to apply a `rerender` action on any buttons that execute any logic for example on whatever contains your error message.

So something like this:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="failure" rendered="{!itFailed}">
    <!-- Bootstrap Error Message Here -->
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:commandButton action = {!someAction} reRender="failure" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use apex:messages

```
<apex:messages layout="block" styleClass="alert alert-danger errors" style="list-style-type: none;" />
```